# Erro ao abrir conexão do XAMPP no MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, xampp

Boa noite, quando eu crio uma conexao no mysql workbench para acessar o XAMPP, aparece essa mensagem em baixo e a frase "could not be feched" ao lado dos submenus da database. Alguma solução?[image: Mensagem de erro]

Comment: Isso acontece porque Xampp instala o MariaDB e não MySql, eles não são 100% compatíveis. Você também vai ter problemas com indices. Remova o MariaDB e instale o MySql para que essas chateações sumam do Workbench.

Comment: Augusto, reinstalei o xampp habilitando a instalção do mysql mas continuou com o erro.

Comment: Vai no esquema e use o assistente de transferência para atualizar o seu modelo. Só um adendo o Xampp não instala o MySql, pode estar escrito MySql porém ele só instala o MariaDB. Para instalar o MySQL tem que fazer o download direto na Oacle.